# Use native style in delegate

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I was initially using the provided roles of `FolderListModel` to display directory content in `TableView`:

```
TableViewColumn {
    role: "fileName"
    title: qsTr("Name")
}
```

But later I started to define custom delegate for various columns. I noticed that when using roles, the font was very native-looking (on Ubuntu), and I didn't have to explicitly specify `color` conditioned on `styleData.selected`, etc. But now with custom delegate, all the native styling is gone, in particular, fonts don't look as smooth anymore. I tried `renderType: Text.NativeRendering`, but still the result doesn't match the native style, mainly in terms of color and anti-aliasing.

So what is a good way to use the native styling (mainly the font family with optimal anti-aliasing) in delegate?

Comment: Did you try [SystemPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-systempalette.html) ? - 
_The SystemPalette type provides access to the Qt application palettes. This provides information about the standard colors used for application windows, buttons and other features_

Comment: I didn't. I was aware of it though. I'll definitely use this. Thank you. But actually the more pressing issue is regarding the font smoothness: somehow the font used in the implicit delegate with "roles" has significantly better anti-aliasing. I tried various font families but none looked as good. So it'd be great if there's a way to know what the implicit font family is (at least on Ubuntu)?